# ISS as a Mars safe house?

Tags: mars, iss

Would it be possible to move the ISS to an orbit of the sun, say 120 million miles away from the sun, putting it halfway between Earth and Mars? If it was purged of oxygen there would be little or no oxidation. Heating and cooling might be tricky! Perhaps it could be a staging/emergency post for Mars?

Comment: Orbits do not work that way. In order to go to Mars, you don't first go half-way to Mars. Look up Hohmann transfer.

Comment: I think the ITN could better be used as we could use the moon as a gravity assist. As I said ISS used as a way station with supplies etc, even fuel maybe. Just in case something going wrong early on in a journey.

Comment: @BernardSmith you cannot "stop at the fuel station" when flying from Earth toward Mars. That's just not how spaceflight works.

Comment: @BernardSmith Do you mean use the ISS as a [Mars cycler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_cycler)?

Comment: Apologies to all, I was not suggesting it should be used as a 'routine' stop at all, but as an outpost for unforeseen occurrences where life/lives might be at stake. That's all I'm asking really!

Comment: @called2voyage I hadn't heard the term before but having read up on it, it does sound interesting?

Comment: @BernardSmith It's the best way I can think of to have an outpost "between" Mars and Earth.

Comment: Earth and Mars can be at the same side of the Sun, but also at opposit sides of the sun. Halfway is not a fixed location and there is no orbit around Sun possible where the ISS would stay between Earth and Mars. The orbits of Earth, Mars and the ISS have different periods. If Earth and Mars will be in minimal distance next time, the ISS may be yery far away at opposite side of the Sun.

Comment: Would it be possible to move ISS to an intermediate solar orbit between that of earth and mars? Yes*  (*with approved credit.  Warranty void above 600 km earth altitude.  Additional propellant and data fees may apply.  Your mileage may vary.)

Comment: @Tristan Also, irradiate at your own risk.

Comment: @called2voyage I figured that was covered in the warranty clause ;-)

Comment: If you really want to put the ISS between Earth and Mars to be an emergency post the more logically places would be in HEO (high earth orbit) or in orbit around Mars itself.  Then if there was a serious problem after launch or at the end of the trip, help would be there.  Obviously timing your departure and arrival is important in case you need to stop at the station.  In between is not possible, as others have already described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting it half-way between Earth and Mars doesn't make as much sense as you think. It's something akin to putting a ship half-way between two other ships. It's a moving target, and doesn't really make sense as a result. The closest is something like the [Deep Space Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Gateway), which orbits the Moon, although that is of questionable value.

There is some discussion of moving the ISS to be a [deep space space station](https://www.space.com/8927-part-space-station-carry-crew-asteroid-nasa.html). At best, a small part of the station could be used. Simply put, the radiation, thermal, and power systems are all designed to be in low Earth orbit, and wouldn't function well at anything else.

A purposely build mission to store fuel could quickly and easily be developed, and would be far easier than trying to bring the entire Space Station somewhere. It would also probably do the job better.

Comment: I understand the radiation issues with LEO vs. elswhere but I have not heard the thermal and power systems are similarly designed for LEO.